# method() missing 1 required argument: 'self', while method() doesn't need any parameters

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

So in order to learn OOP-programming, we are tasked du build classes. These classes should us allow getting input() via the terminal. Like "enter 'a''' for a list of all books.

This is my first method and it does not want to work. It SHOULD not take any parameters, it doesn't need any since there is one list it is tasked to read out.

So my code looks like this:

```
from Library import *

while(True):

print("blabla explaining how to use the program, do you want to 'a', print a list of all books, 'b'.....")
user_choice = input

if(user_choice == 'a'):
    Library.list_books()
if(user_choice == 'b'):
    #etc.
```

And the library method looks as follows:

```
from Book import *

def list_books(self):
    for Book.Book in Book.book_list:
        print(Book.Book.name)
```

As you see, it doesn't really need anything in order to function. Why is it then, that it wants a parameter. Obviously, if I remove the 'self' it would work, but that is, as far as I know, not conventional. The only fix I found was adding @classmethod. My boss did not approve of that though and called it cheating.

It may be, that I haven't fully understood what the 'self' does/is, but for now, all I know is, that it doesn't work and I am out of ideas. I am still researching it but either I am too stupid or the sources don't do a good job explaining it to me. I've just been programming python for, like, 2 weeks now and have VERY mild Java skills, so my general programming knowledge is still limited. If you have any sources that explain it well or which help you I'd be very glad to read them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ‘self’ parameter is automatically added by some IDEs. It is used when the method belongs to a class, in order to access other fields and functions inside that class.  In this case, because your method is not in a class, you can safely remove it.

Comment: @JPeroutek so if I don't need it I can just leave it out? I thought it was kinda mandatory and my IDE tells me when it is missing.

Comment: As long as you don’t reference it inside the method, you should be fine leaving it out.

Comment: @JPeroutek I mean, it works now, but now it sais  [pylint] Method has no argument,

Comment: I think I will just add another list, just so I can give it listA or listB

Comment: Hooray, now [pylint is complaining about the first argument not being 'Self'. I just don't get what self does. What does self give to the method?

Comment: I am still having the same problem with another function that gets the book_name. Can I just leave self out all of the time if I dont need it? When do I need it? Ugh

Comment: I'll type it up in an answer.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @JPeroutek No pressure, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self` parameter is often added to methods automatically by IDEs.  It is primarily used when the method is contained inside of a class.

Take for example the `Book` class below.

```
class Book:
    author = ""
    title = ""

    def __init__(self, author, title):
        self.author = author
        self.title = title

    def print_book_information(self):
        print("'%s' by %s" % (self.title, self.author))
```

Since you're just starting with OOP, a lot of this is going to be a bit confusing.  First, we declare the class type Book.

```
class Book:
```

The next two lines declare variables associated with the Book class.  In this case, we want to store the `author` of the book, as well as the `title` of the book.

```
    author = ""
    title = ""
```

The next two functions, if you noticed, both have a `self` parameter.  The parameter `self` references back to the book that you've created.  so if I create a book like so:

```
my_book = Book('Ayn Rand', 'Atlas Shrugged')
```

It will execute the `__init__` method, which sets the value of `author` and `title` for our specific book.

```
self.author = author # Sets our author to be 'Ayn Rand'
self.title = title   # Sets our title to be 'Atlas Shrugged'
```

Now that our class is made, we can do something like

```
>>> my_book.print_book_information()
'Atlas Shrugged' by Ayn Rand
```

Notice in the method `print_book_information` how we use the word `self` to reference our author and title?  The `self` essentially allows the method to know which specific book you are looking at.  Otherwise, the method wouldn't know which book you wanted the title or author for.

Also, in the question you noted that you have a very mild Java background.  `self` performs a similar function to the `this` keyword from Java, except that you have to include it as a parameter in Python, whereas you don't reference it in the parameters in Java.  The following two methods are essentially the same:

```
# Python
class Hello:
    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hello!")

// Java
public class Hello
{
    public void say_hello()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Might be a typo or two in the java, haven't used it in the past 5 years or so.

Comment: But what if I need self but no other parameters? like now I want to use the method to print the books i stored in that class. but if I type 'Library.list_books()' it sais it is missing one required positional argument

Comment: As it stands, your current `list_books` method is not in a class.   So the `self` parameter doesn't carry any special meaning.  You could rename it to `cat`, and it would still not matter.  You can remove it from the function definition.

Comment: I have 3 .py documents, one with books and a list of books, the other one, the libray which has the method print_list(self) and a main .py which calls the method               so when I am in the main and write Library.print_list() I get this error. How do I avoid this problem without letting out the (self)?`

Comment: @Maritn Ge Would you mind adding your full code into the question?  I’m afraid that I’m a little lost when it comes to your secondary question.